# Windows 10 install. Restart in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

During the upgrade from W7 to W10 there is a reboot after about 25% if installation.
When the reboot is finished it starts in Windows 7. So the installation seems to fail, but I can't see in the errorlog what's wrong. 
I already shut off the virusscanner and disconnect the external ubs drive and usbflashcard

I can't find what can cause this

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set on 'clean start' [as described here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135)

Comment: Describe it here and provide the link as a reference.